# Euler problem10 not getting ans on output

Tags: java

I am getting  output in more than 20 minute is there any way to reduce the time to get out put quickly

```
public class Problem10 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
long temp =0;   
 int n=2000000;
 for(long i=2; i<n; i++){
 System.out.println((i));
     boolean isprime = true;
  for(long j=2; j<i; j++){
       if(i%j==0){
        isprime =false;    
           break;
          }
      }

  if(isprime)
   {temp +=i;

   }

  }
   System.out.println(temp);

} 

}
```

Comment: Given the amount of computation involved in your code, it will take a good amount of time. You might be better off putting a print statement in your `if(isprime)` condition to see the overall progress.

Comment: You are getting nothing, or are you still waiting for an answer? I think this problem is about how to test efficiently for primes. You might have a look into that. Also be careful that the sum does not overflow the variable temp, which is only an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

If I calculate complexity of your program which is roughly `BigO(n*n)`. And here if `n` value is `2000000` then it would take `2000000 * 2000000` iteration to complete the entire task.

Which is significantly large amount of time. I would suggest you put `println` with in your loop which reminds you that it still running. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your data type is too small to hold the value so change it either in **long** or BigInteger type  to optimization you can change your lncorrect logic to other  logic. see the project euler site

Answer (score 0):

change the datatype of temp and int to long it will work